# Сжимается круглый cell.ImageView при нажатии на секцию

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Сжимается круглый cell.ImageView при нажатии на секцию, скриншот:
http://cs619525.vk.me/v619525197/18482/HGLNDJ_Tpew.jpg

Код:

```
 [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[ArrayImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(60, 60);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
    [cell.imageView.image drawInRect:imageRect];
    cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [cell.imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [cell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    [cell.imageView.layer setCornerRadius:30];
    [cell.imageView.layer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60)];
    [cell.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60)];
    cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

В чем проблема?

**Обновление**

Но если прокрутить вниз и снова подняться вверх, то картинки снова станут круглыми, и при нажатии на секцию она не уменьшится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас кастомная ячейка, но вы используете "встроенный" imageView.
Сделайте свой imageView (назовите его, avatarImageView, например).
И работайте с ним, на 99 процентов уверен, что после этого все будет хорошо.

Comment: Я задумался об этом, но думал можно настроить и этот

Comment: попробуйте, делов-то на 2 минуты